# Counting Elements in an Array, Adding them to 2 Objects within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var arr = ['cat','cat','dog','penguin','chicken','chicken']

function orgAnimals(input)
   var obj = {};
   for (var i = 0 ; i < input.length; i++) {
      obj[input[i]] = obj[input[i]] || 0;
      obj[input[i]]++
   }
return obj;
}
```

So this gives me {cat:2, dog:1, penguin:1, chicken:2,}

I want to split the object up into 2 different objects and put it in an array so it looks like

```
[{cat:2, dog:1} {penguin:1, chicken:2 }]
```

I tried an `if` statement to make that work but it's not.
`if (input[i]==='cat'||'dog')` still gives me the same output as before.

Any hints? Am I using the operator incorrectly?

Comment: `if (input[i]==='cat'||'dog')` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Golf time, I suppose

```js
var arr = ['cat','cat','dog','penguin','chicken','chicken']

function orgAnimals(input) {
    return input.reduce((a, b) => {
     var i = ['cat','dog'].indexOf(b) === -1 ? 1 : 0;
       return b in a[i] ? a[i][b]++ : a[i][b] = 1, a
    }, [{},{}]);
}

console.log( orgAnimals(arr) );
```

Same logic, but a little more readable, where you check if the iterated value is either `cat` or `dog` and insert into the array based on a condition

```js
var arr = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'penguin', 'chicken', 'chicken']

function orgAnimals(input) {
    var arr = [{}, {}];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    
        if ( input[i] === 'dog' || input[i] === 'cat') {
         if ( input[i] in arr[0] ) {
             arr[0][ input[i] ] = arr[0][ input[i] ] + 1;
            } else {
             arr[0][ input[i] ] = 1;
            }
        } else {
         if ( input[i] in arr[1] ) {
             arr[1][ input[i] ] = arr[1][ input[i] ] + 1;
            } else {
             arr[1][ input[i] ] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log( orgAnimals(arr) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create 2 separate objects and then combine them in your return statement. So something like this:

```
if ((input[i] == 'cat') || (input[i] == 'dog'))){
  obj1[input[i]] = obj1[input[i]] || 0;
  obj1[input[i]]++
}
else if ((input[i] == 'penguin') || (input[i] == 'chicken')){
  obj2[input[i]] = obj2[input[i]] || 0;
  obj2[input[i]]++
}
return {obj1, obj2}
```